# Recordset does not populate listbox - MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, t-sql, ms-access, listbox, recordset

I'm trying to populate a listbox in a form using VBA in MS Access.
I've done this multiple times before and never had an issue but now the listbox does not get populated.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    linkedOrders = linkedOrderList

    qGetLinks = "SELECT *Various fields from table* FROM *Table* WHERE *Conditioned_field* IN(" & linkedOrders & ")"
    Set rsLinks = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qGetLinks, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    Me.selListRS.RowSourceType = "Query/Table"
    Me.selListRS.RowSource = ""

    Set Me.selListRS.Recordset = rsLinks
End Sub
```

Please note that 'linkedOrderList' is a Global variable that is populated correctly upon loading the form.

I've tried googling the issue but since I'm using the exact same code (save for variable names) as I always do I cant seem to find any solutions and I'm nearing my wit's end.

I've ran the code using breakpoints to make sure that all variables and recordsets gets populated as expected and found no issues there.
The RS 'rsLinks' gets the expected result from my SQL-query, so no beef there either.

I've checked all my spellings a few times but as far as I can see, all is gravy there.

Comment: As a side note, that query is dangerously open to injection attacks.

Comment: If I remove `Me.selListRS.RowSourceType = "Query/Table"` and `Me.selListRS.RowSource = ""` it works for me.

Comment: In addition to the solution below correcting the value for RowSourceType shouldn't that be `Me.seListRS.RowSource = rsLinks` (i.e. not `.Recordset')

Comment: @ThomA - This is an internal system only used by employees and is slowly but surely being phased out in favor of new modern systems, so that is not really a worry at the moment. However, I'm curious what part makes it vulnerable to injection attacks? I am a bit green in the world of developing and still learning so I would love an explanation so that I can learn for future reference.

Comment: @CHill60 - Hmm, that doesn't seem to be the case as it works now using Shahram's solution. However, I am in no way an expert and am open to be corrected :)

Comment: My solution works if you set these properties in the properties window instead of doing it in code, because then you get the "Query/Table" / "Table/Query" choice automatically right because you can select it from a drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Me.selListRS.RowSourceType = "Query/Table"
```

Edit it as following:

```
Me.selListRS.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
```

Comment: That did the trick, I cannot believe I missed that all this time!
Thank you very much for your time and expertise.